# Lock some features of my app depending on who logs into (AD auth based)

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

I need an advice please.
I have an C# app (and WPF for design) with an ActiveDirectory authentification required. I currently just check if the Username and Password are corrects before log the user in. But, now, I have to grant access to some features depending on who log onto my app (some users may have full access, some others will have locked features).

I wonder how to do this ... 
If someone have an example, or any guideline :)

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It realy depends on what your Architecture should look like. I would suggest different modules each including a initialization class which may add buttons to a menu in a init method. Then you could use annotation on this class including the required user-rights. When ever you initialize your whole application you could iterate over the initialization classes and call the init method if the user has access.

Answer (score 1):

You could create classes that implements the `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` interfaces and override the application thread's default identity in your `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a custom principal with an anonymous identity at startup
        CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(customPrincipal);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

You could then use the [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to perform either declarative or imperative security checks throughout your application.

Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/) for more information and a complete example.

Comment: Very good blog, I'll keep it. thank's. Anyway, it doesn't apply to my needs :) But I found a solution (added to my post)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.
1st : I check if user is authenticated. If true, "goto" 2nd ;)

```
        public bool IsAuthenticated(string username, string passwd, string domain)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, username, passwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
            {
                Filter = "(objectClass=user)",
                SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
            };
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            return (result != null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Authentication Error.\n" + ex.Message);
        }
```

2nd : I check which group the user is in. My access differs mainly on 3 groups. I used a simple conditionnal statement like this :

```
            if (IsAuthenticated(user, password, LdapCmb))
            {
                // Connection ok
                if (AuthenticateGroup(user, password, userLdap, GroupADM))
                {
                    accessRights = "ADM";
                    // Variable passed to another class (for locking down some contents)
                }
                else if (AuthenticateGroup(user, password, userLdap, OtherGroup1))
                {
                    accessRights = "OTHER1";
                    // Variable passed to another class (for locking down some contents)
                }
                else if (AuthenticateGroup(user, password, userLdap, OtherGroup2))
                {
                    accessRights = "OTHER2";
                    // Variable passed to another class (for locking down some contents)
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, "You are not authorized to use this application.", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    logIt.AppendText("User " + user + " isn't granted for use");
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }
                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, "You are not authorized to use this application.", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    logIt.AppendText("User " + user + " isn't granted for use");

                Close();
            }
```

And finally, here is the "authenticateGroup" method :

```
        public bool AuthenticateGroup(string userName, string password, string domain, string group)
    {

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password);
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
            {
                Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + userName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")))"
            };
            SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

            foreach (string GroupPath in result.Properties["memberOf"])
            {
                if (GroupPath.Contains(group))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It's certainly not the best method... but at least, it works as expected at this moment. Now I have to test it deeper.

Thank's anyway.